# C++ equivalent of PHP's pack()

Tags: php, c++

My question is simple.

Is there an equivalent of PHP's `pack()` and `unpack()` function in the C++ STL?
If no, is there an alternative to achieve the same goal?

https://www.php.net/pack

Thanks.

Comment: Not in the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is serializing data, you can use Google protocol buffers to achieve it.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/

Answer (score 2):

There is no serialization mechanism in the STL. Depending on what you want to do you could either use a [library such as the one in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or you could [write your own serialization code](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html), which can be a viable alternative especially if your data is rather simple.

Answer (score 2):

A while back I wrote a small a library in C that does this functionality.  I placed my code on Google code here: [code.google.com/p/packlib/](http://code.google.com/p/packlib/)

Answer (score 0):

Structs are very much like the unpack function within PHP.

These pieces of code, are basically equivalent.

**PHP:**

```
define('ISP_TINY', 4);
class IS_TINY
{
    const PACK = 'CCCC';
    const UNPACK = 'CSize/CType/CReqI/CSubT';

    public $Size = 4;
    public $Type = ISP_TINY;
    public $ReqI;
    public $SubT;

    public function __construct($rawPacket)
    {
        $pkClass = unpack($this::UNPACK, $rawPacket);
        foreach ($this as $property => $value)
        {
            $this->$property = $pkClass[$property];
        }
    }
}
```

**C++:**

```
#define ISP_TINY = 4;
struct IS_TINY // General purpose 4 byte packet
{
    byte Size; // Always 4
    byte Type; // Always ISP_TINY
    byte ReqI;
    byte SubT;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I needed the same functionality so I wrote a single-header library for this. It supports most of the functionality from php's `pack() / unpack()`. The library is available on [github here](https://github.com/Waqar144/phpack).