# pack/unpack functions for C++

Tags: c++, serialization, pack, unpack

NOTE: I know that this has been asked many times before, but none of the questions have had a link to a concrete, portable, maintained library for this.

I need a C or C++ library that implements Python/Ruby/Perl like `pack`/`unpack` functions. Does such a library exist?

EDIT: Because the data I am sending is simple, I have decided to just use `memcpy`, pointers, and the `hton*` functions. Do I need to manipulate a `char` in any way to send it over the network in a platform agnostic manner? (the `char` is only used as a byte, not as a character).

Comment: Could you explain what `pack`/`unpack` do in those languages?

Comment: Pack and unpack are used to turn variables into a binary string and vice-versa, respectively. They are very useful for creating packets and binary files and other binary interactions. The languages that I mentioned have this function in their standard library. C/C++ don't.

Comment: Oh hmm... FYI, this might not even be possible. It would require a great deal of metaprogramming (or IDE support) to get all the field information and such... the only native language I know that could probably do this is [D](http://dlang.org/).

Comment: I mean something along the lines of `sprintf`, just the specifiers would be for binary data. Just the same sort of giant `switch` statement.

Comment: I wrote a small header only library for this: [Php pack/unpack C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194081/2279422) in case anyone is looking for same functionality with a similar API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)?

Answer (score 6):

In C/C++ usually you would just write a `struct` with the various members in the correct order (correct packing may require compiler-specific pragmas) and dump/read it to/from file with a raw `fwrite`/`fread` (or `read`/`write` when dealing with C++ streams). Actually, `pack` and `unpack` were born to read stuff generated with this method.

If you instead need the result in a buffer instead of a file it's even easier, just copy the structure to your buffer with a `memcpy`.

If the representation must be portable, your main concerns are is byte ordering and fields packing; the first problem can be solved with the various `hton*` functions, while the second one with compiler-specific directives.

In particular, many compilers support the `#pragma pack` directive (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=vs-2019) for VC++, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) for gcc), that allows you to manage the (unwanted) padding that the compiler may insert in the `struct` to have its fields aligned on convenient boundaries.

Keep in mind, however, that on some architectures it's not allowed to access fields of particular types if they are not aligned on their natural boundaries, so in these cases you would probably need to do some manual `memcpy`s to copy the raw bytes to variables that are properly aligned.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `#pragma`s? I use GCC.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: added some links about `#pragma pack`.

Comment: hton*/ntoh* only convert between host by order (may be big or little endian) and network byte order (effectively big endian).  They do not provide a way to serialize/deserialize values which are stored _little endian_ in a portable manner.

Comment: I wrote a small header only library for this: [Php pack/unpack C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194081/2279422) in case anyone is looking for same functionality with a similar API

Answer (score 2):

Yes: Use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>` to operate on the byte representation of a variable. Every variable `T x;` can be accessed as a byte array via `char * p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x)`; and `p` can be treated like a pointer to the first element of a an array `char[sizeof(T)]`. For example:

```
char buf[100];
double q = get_value();

char const * const p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&q);
std::copy(p, p + sizeof(double), buf);

// more stuff like that

some_stream.write(buf) //... etc.
```

And to go back:

```
double r;

std::copy(data, data + sizeof(double), reinterpret_cast<char *>(&r));
```

In short, you don't need a dedicated `pack`/`unpack` in C++, because the language already allows you access to its variables' binary representation as a standard part of the language.

Comment: I know. I want a pack/unpack for portable representation, not local byte manipulation.

Comment: You're guaranteed to get a valid object back only for types that are trivially copyable.  I'm sure you already know this, but you didn't say it.

Comment: This is not portable at all. You are not considering endianess for starters, and of course it only works for POD (plain old data) types.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: Well, what's a "portable" way of storing floats? What I'm saying is that you can use the byte-access to *implement* any sort of serialization that you like. For example, you can read/write unsigned integers with the usual algebraic manipulations (`buf[0] = n % 256; buf [1] = (n / 256) % 256;`, etc. (Though you need unsigned chars in that case.) And yes, this is only for fundamental types (not even PODs).